# How can I ensure a value is contained within an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

The following is my code :

It is for testing  a prime number generator which creates and populates an arraylist first n prime numbers. In my test, I create an array of known prime numbers, and then use my method to construct an arraylist of the first 50 (knownPrimes.length) prime numbers. A random number is then picked, and I would like to assertTrue that every prime number picked using my method nextRandomPrime (which picks a number from my arraylist of unknown/generated primes) is contained within the array knownPrimes. How can I do this ?

In psuedocode what I would like to do is :

```
assertTrue(createdPrimeList.nextRandomPrime is a value in the array knownPrimes);
```

Here is what I have gotten so far :

```
 public void comparePrimes() {
    int[] knownPrimes = new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 
      31,  37,  41,  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71, 
      73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 
      127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 
      179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229 };

    Primes createdPrimeList = new Primes (knownPrimes.length);
    for (int index = 0; index < noOfTests; index++) //noOfTests is a global variable
    {
      assertTrue( createdPrimeList.nextRandomPrime( ) IS IN knownPrimes );//line I am struggling with
    }
  }
```

Would anyone please be able to help me out ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

Use binary search. You can use [`Arrays.binarySearch(int[] array, int key)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5b%5d,%20int%29).

In order to verify whether next value is stored in `knownPrimes` you should do this:

```
int nextValue = createdPrimeList.nextRandomPrime();
if (Arrays.binarySearch(knownPrimes, nextValue) >= 0) {
    System.out.println("The value is already stored in known primes");
}
```

Comment: Would I not need to know the index of the value in knownPrimes to do this ?

Comment: No, you don't need to know the index of the key in question. Binary search works with a sorted list of elements only.

Comment: So in my case how would I implement this ? Sorry, I don't really understand.

Comment: @user476033 - `Arrays.binarySearch` will search a sorted array you give it for `key`. If it succeeds it returns a value >= 0, otherwise the return is < 0 (invalid array index).

Comment: Ahh I see, thank you very much, so in my case, my code will be :

    for (int index = 0; index < noOfTests; index++){
      int nextValue = createdPrimeList.nextRandomPrime();
      assertTrue((Arrays.binarySearch(knownPrimes, nextValue) >= 0)); 
    }

Comment: Just saw your edit, Roman...thank you very much, apologies for my indentation - I'm unsure how to indent in comments !

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339269/how-can-i-ensure-a-value-is-contained-within-an-array/4339294#4339294), [`Arrays.binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) is probably your best friend.

```
System.out.println(" looking up " + lookup + " -> " +
    ((Arrays.binarySearch(PRIMES, lookup) >= 0) ? "found" : "not found"));
```

If you array is not already sorted, sort it first:

```
Arrays.sort(PRIMES);
System.out.println(" looking up " + lookup + " -> " +
    ((Arrays.binarySearch(PRIMES, lookup) >= 0) ? "found" : "not found"));
```

---

And if you have [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) (or an old version of Java without `Arrays.binarySearch()`, then [`ArrayUtils.contains`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html) is also your friend:

```
System.out.println(" looking up " + lookup + " -> " +
    ((ArrayUtils.contains(PRIMES, lookup)) ? "found" : "not found"));
```

---

*In these snippets, `PRIMES` is an `int[]` containing your numbers for matching, and `lookup` is an `int` containing your randomly generated prime number.*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Quick question, what is meant when you ask if my arraylist is not already sorted ? As in the way I am sorting it, I believe it should first put in 2 then 3, then 5 .... the nth prime number. Would this be considered sorted ? Thanks a lot for your reply :)

Comment: @user476033: in your question, you say you want to see if the randomly generated prime number is in your array of primes, `knownPrimes`. In that case, you already entered the values in the right order, from the smallest to the biggest number. However if you are in a situation where that's not the case (your array is shuffled), then you need to sort the array first (have the values be in the correct order, from smallest to biggest). That's where `Arrays.sort()` comes in, as it will sort your elements in place.